Variability in the dataset explained by a subset of variables
Let's assume a centred data matrix $X_{n \times p}$ of $p$ variables, where each variable has unit variance. PCA can be thought about as a rotation of the coordinate system that diagonalises the covariance matrix $\Sigma_{p\times p}$, resulting in a new covariance matrix $\hat \Sigma$. That is a desired property, as the total variance in the dataset can be then formulated as
\begin{align}
    \operatorname{tr}(\hat \Sigma) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^p \lambda_i
\end{align}
and the fraction of variance explained by the first $k$ components is
\begin{align}
    {\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \lambda_i}/{\sum\limits_{i=1}^p \lambda_i}
\end{align}
Imagine now that we regress all variables from $X$ against the first $k$ principal components and then calculate $R^2$. How would the $R^2$ correspond to the variance explained using the eigenvalues ratio? Shouldn't it be... equal?

What do you mean by "$R^2$" in a regression of $p$ variables against $k$ variables??

Without the requested clarification, this question looks off-topic according to our norms here on CV, so I have refunded your bounty and closed it pending an explanation of what you mean by "calculate $R^2.$"  This might just be a matter of my ignorance or misunderstanding, but I don't want you to lose that bounty and then discover nobody else can understand the question, either.
